# Connecting web app to SQL Server on Azure VM

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, iaas

I have a SQL Server on Azure VM and I am trying to connect to it from my web app. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have searched and I have not found one where it connecting to SQL on VM (iAAS). I have only seen tutorials connect to the SQL Server (PAAS). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask a question without providing an error message or _some_ kind of information that gives context on the problem. Given this is a network/firewall question, you need to explain _where_ your web app is. On premise? Azure VM? Azure web app?. Lastly can you simply connect using sql tools? This is _Basic_ troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi nangel, if my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server on an Azure VM is exactly the same as connecting to SQL Server on a physical server or a VMWare VM.

You will need to ensure that the VM has either a static IP Address or a DNS name. This is what you would use to connect to it from your client. You will also have to ensure that you deal with firewalls.

Is your client also an Azure VM or is it on-premises?

Comment: Especially firewall is a topic often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two Azure documents may help you:

1. [Connect to a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect).
   This topic describes how to connect to your SQL Server instance running on an Azure virtual machine.
2. [Connect your application to Azure SQL Database managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-connect-app).
   Today you have multiple choices when deciding how and where you host your application.Whatever choice you made, you can connect it to a Managed Instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: fyi - first link is out of date.